# Being both Serializable and IsSerializable in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I've got some DTOs in a project separate from my GWT project, and am trying to use them as DTOs inside the GWT project. They implement `Serializable` for use with another service. Currently, because I do not wish to reference them all in the GWT RPC service interface method signatures, I have to do the technique of "tricking" GWT into whitelisting the classes for serialization by making dummy methods that do nothing and are never called.

I don't want to create separate `IsSerializable` classes in the GWT project in order to not duplicate code, but dummy methods aren't desirable either.

One alternative I have thought of would be to add (a) GWT jar(s) as a dependency to the project containing my DTOs so that they may implement both `Serializable` and `IsSerializable`. Searches on the topic of being both `Serializable` and `IsSerializable` only brings up discussions on choosing between the two.

Can a class implement both `Serializable` and `IsSerializable` without complications?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of GWT are you using? If it's recent (> 1.4) then, as far as I understand, [GWT documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_Server.html#Does_the_GWT_RPC_system_support_the_use_of_java.io.Serializable) says that you can directly use your `Serializable` objects:

> the GWT Team felt that the community was generally aware of these
>   issues but preferred the convenience of being able to use the standard
>   java.io.Serializable interface rather than to have their classes
>   implement the isSerializable  marker interface, although both marker
>   interfaces to denote serializable classes are supported in GWT 1.4 and
>   later. Considering this, the GWT Team made changes to the GWT RPC
>   system to support the use of java.io.Serializable for data transfer
>   objects (commonly referred to as DTOs) that would be transferred over
>   the wire. However, there is one condition to enable support for
>   java.io.Serializable in the new GWT RPC system.

Comment: Yes, but to my understanding, the regular Serializable classes don't get added to the serialization policy whitelist unless they are referenced in method signatures, thus leading to the undesirable "dummy methods", while IsSerializable classes are automatically added to this whitelist.

Comment: "the regular Serializable classes don't get added to the serialization policy whitelist unless they are referenced in method signatures ... while IsSerializable classes are automatically added"  I did not know that, but it would explain why I had been having trouble with Serializable but it went away when I changed it to IsSerializable.  If you had asked me 5 minutes ago, I would have said the requirement to be in a method signature was true for both Serializable and IsSerializable.  Do you have a reference to where this is documented?

Answer (score 0):

I tried implementing both `IsSerializable` and `Serializable`, since I want to be able to save my DTOs into Http session and replicate them thru a cluster. Also I like the idea of allowing old clients (with non valid policies) to be able to use the new services (of course the ones with same signature) that `IsSerializable` provides. But GWT goes crazy (the client deserializer tries to instantiate a class named as a String content) when falling back to 1.3.3 behaviour (no valid policy) and having both interfaces implemented in the DTOs. As soon as I get rid of `Serializable`, GWT RPC system works ok again.

EDIT: Strangely enough I tried again after removing `Serializable` and put it back in my DTO. And it worked. I was always testing in development mode, maybe a bug with the plugin?